# AbstractBaseUser email as username validation

Tags: python, django, validation, authentication, django-templates

I have the following code in Django 1.6 which works fine with the email as username. But I would like to check if the email is set in the email field and raise and validation error if is not set.
Also, I would like to check if the email expression is correct. I have read the documentation but I am confused and I don't find how to deal with it.

The password validation works well.

Here is my ModelForm:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .models import Usuario

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Introduce tu nombre', 'required': 'true'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Introduce tus apellidos'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Introduce una contraseña'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repetir contraseña', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Introduce tu correo electrónico'}))

class Meta:
   model = Usuario
   fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

def clean_password2(self):
    # Comprueba que los dos password son iguales
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Las contraseñas no coinciden')

    return password2


def save (self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
    if commit: 
        user.save()
    return user
```

The signup form in my template:

```
<form class="auth_form" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="name_box">
                <label for="first_name">Nombre</label>
                {{ form.first_name }}
                {{ form.first_name.errors }}
            </div>
            <div class="name_box">
                <label for="id_last_name">Apellidos</label>
                {{ form.last_name }}
                {{ form.last_name.errors }}
            </div>
            <label for="id_email">Correo electrónico</label>
            {{ form.email }}
            {{ form.email.errors }}
            <label for="id_password1">Contraseña</label>
            {{ form.password1 }}
            <label for="id_password2">Repetir contraseña</label>
            {{ form.password2 }}
            {{ form.password2.errors }}
            <input type="submit" value="Registrarme">
        </form>
```

I don't know how to begin...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Email Required:**

If you don't have `required=False` in your Email form field, it will be required to fill the email in the form, if not the form will raise an error. So right now, you need to fill the email to submit the form.

Anyway if you want to make sure of this, you could add a `def clean_email` and manage the save of the email as you want.

*(los campos del formulario por defecto son requeridos, salvo que añadas un "required=False" al definir el campo. Si quisieras algo mas de personalización a la hora de añadir el email podrías crear un `def clean_email` y añadir lo que quieras)*

**Email Format:**

When you create a field that is `EmailField` it has to be with the format `XXX@XXX.XX` so Django will manage this for you